# select child links in a div problem

Tags: html, css

I have always had a problem with selecting child links in a div but now I have decided to ask you guys what am I missing here!

I try this:

```
#navigation a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}



<div id="navigation">

<a href="#">
   <h1>home</h1>
</a>


<a href="#">
   <h1>new</h1>
</a>


<a href="#">
   <h1>contact</h1>
</a>


</div>
```

but it doesnt work! the links get some default settings from the browser or something like that!

Comment: You should consider using a single H1 tag. Also heading tags are block-level elements where link tags (a) are inline elements. Don't put a block-level element into an inline element as your HTML will not validate. Try <h2><a href="#">Home</a></h2> instead.

Answer (score 2):

try removing the :link,

also you should try to only have 1 h1 title per page for SEO reasons.

Comment: I dont really understand SEO! do you think that I should remove the h1 from my navigation? what should I use? and where should I use h1? my boss adds the  navigation in the end of the page and he told me thats for SEO reasons because google for example when it will index pages it will read first the content then the navigation links

Comment: Try using the h1 tag for what the page is specific for such as the page description, having multiple h1 tags makes it hard for search engines to be sure what your page is about making it rank lower.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably clicked on those links so they're no longer `a:link` but now `a:visited`.  Just get rid of the pseudo-class:

```
#navigation a { ... }
```